# formatting strings (variable+text)

Tags: php

I need to add 2 numbers together.

```
$num1 = 40;
$num2 = 20;

$num12 = $num1 + ':' + $num2;
```

For some reason this outputs as `60` and it should be `40:20`.

is there some way to format this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is. use php concatenation (`.`) not javascript concatenation (`+`).

```
$num12 = $num1 . ':' . $num2;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is string concatenation.

In php you need the `.`-operator , not the `+`:

$num12 = $num1 . ':' . $num2;